# Mongo lab statement regarding internal networks

Tags: mongodb, networking, google-cloud-platform, mlab

I'm not sure how to phrase this question or even if it's relevant here.

I'm researching a solution to move our in-house MongoDB installation to a cloud-based db as a service solution in Mongo lab.

The company has stated here http://docs.mlab.com/security/#network that if I deploy the DB in my region (I use google cloud)

> When you connect to your mLab database from within the same datacenter/region, you communicate over your cloud hosting provider’s internal network.

How is that statement possible?

When I create a DB at Mongo lab I get an external URL to connect to

```
ds021984.mlab.com -> 104.154.103.88 instead of an internal host name 10.x.x.x
```

So how can that address be external thus effecting my latency deeply?

Am I missing something ? How is that statement possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only time you can use the internal IP to address a VM in GCP is if that VM is in the same network resource (and hence, the same GCP account). GCP is smart enough to know if the external IP being addressed is a GCP address, and will route the traffic such that it does not leave the region. This is pretty evident when you ping an external IP from another VM in the region, you'll typically get sub-millisecond response times.